# db2 SQLCODE=-243, SQLSTATE=36001 ERROR

Tags: db2

I am using the DB2Driver in my code like

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
```

and I am getting the result set in my java code which is scroll sensitive. my sql query look like this `select distinct day , month , year from XXX` . here table XXX is read only for the user which I am using ... so it is giving the following error

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-243, SQLSTATE=36001, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURSH200C3, DRIVER=3.51.90` .. I know this is the problem of read only .. but when i try to execute the same query in db2 control center it is working

please help me out in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PubLib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0243.htm) is your friend :-)

> **SQL0243N**
> SENSITIVE cursor <cursor-name> cannot be defined for the specified SELECT statement.
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> Cursor <cursor-name> is defined as SENSITIVE, but the content of the SELECT statement requires DB2 to build a temporary result table of the cursor, and DB2 cannot guarantee that changes made outside this cursor will be visible. This situation occurs when the content of the query makes the result table read-only. For example, if the query includes a join, the result table is read-only. In these cases, the cursor must be defined as INSENSITIVE or ASENSITIVE.
>
> The statement cannot be processed.
>
> **User response:**
>
> Either change the content of the query to yield a result table that is not read-only, or change the type of the cursor to INSENSITIVE or ASENSITIVE.

If you can't change the cursor type, look in to the use of materialised queriey tables. These are like views but also provide temporary backing storage for the data so that it's not forced read-only by the query type.

Whether that will help in situations where you've forced the user to be read only, I'm not entirely sure but you *may* be able to have different permission on the materialised data and real data (unfortunately, I haven't done a lot of work with these, certainly none where permissions were locked down to read-only level).

Comment: @ paxdiablo .. How to make change the content of the query to yield a result table that is not read-only

Comment: You need to look into materialised queries. They're like views but maintain the data independently, after a query is done on them. I can't tell from your question whether you've _explicitly_ marked the table read-only for that user or whether it's the `distinct` forcing a temporary table build. If the former, materialised queries _may_ not work (I've never tried this).